# Redirect Registered Customer issue

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, customer, redirect

i add this condition on the Proceed to Checkout button:

```
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php else: ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Proceed to Checkout')) ?>" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif?>
```

So when a user is not login on my store will be redirected to Login / Register page. I made a custom function to redirect the customers after register to checkout page if the was in Shopping Cart else redirect to My Account. But I don't know what is wrong, because now after register I am redirect only to My Account. So I want to redirect customer after registration to the Checkout page if the customer was in the Shopping Cart else to My Account. This is my function:

```
   public function customerRegistration(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
   {
      if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1){
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
         }
    else
        {
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->sendResponse();
            exit;
        }
         Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCart('0');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIsFromCheckout('0');
   }
```

and this is my observer in the config.xml

```
    <customer_register_success>
        <observers>
          <customerredirect>
            <class>customerredirect/observer_customer</class>
            <method>customerRegistration</method>
          </customerredirect>
        </observers>
    </customer_register_success>
```

Update:

i have found something like this to save the last x Url's in array, maybe someone can tell me how I can adapt this for my code? Thank you

```
$urlHistory = (array) Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMyUrlHistory();
while (is_array($urlHistory) && count($urlHistory) > 3) {
    array_shift($urlHistory);   
}
$urlHistory[] = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setMyUrlHistory($urlHistory);
```

Anyone?

Comment: Where do you set "setIsFromCart" and "setIsFromCheckout" ?

Comment: I am on skype I can show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may depend on different reasons and maybe more of one, so make different tests:

**First check:**

Make sure you have implemented the **form_key** in your login page

**Second check:**

Make sure you configured to not redirect to dashboard:

```
Admin > System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Login Options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in
```

**Third Option:**

Disable your observer and try adding an hidden input field in your registration page just after the form tag opening (template file is `register.phtml`):

```
<input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" />
```

This is according to `_redirectSuccess` method in `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`.

You will have to add the if condition you used in your controller of course. According to your code:

```
...
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCart() == 1 || Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIsFromCheckout() == 1): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('onestepcheckout/index', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" />
<?php else: ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately no one solution not work

Comment: Just tried on my local installation and works fine. Make sure you do not have two "success_url" fields in your register.phtml